# Select elements by "Name" in R

Tags: r

> select_elemtents <- c("A","D")

> set <- list(A = XY, B = XYZ,C = XYZAV, D= XYZAVW)

where XY and XYZ and so on are lists themselves...

i want to select only the lists, which are specified by select_elements, so if i take

> select_elements <- c("A", "B")

then there should be something like

> subset <- list(XY, XYZ)

> or when i want select_elements <- c("B", "C")

> subset <- list(XYZ, XYZAV)

is it possible to grab the elements by string and not by position?

Comment: `set[select_elements]`

Comment: @langtang: sorry but can you please write just a little more? =)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a named list, say `set`, you can select a subset of elements of that list, as follows:

```
select_elements <- c("A","D")

set <- list(A = "XY", B = "XYZ",C = "XYZAV", D= "XYZAVW")

set[select_elements]
```

Output:

```
$A
[1] "XY"

$D
[1] "XYZAVW"
```